# Update field to correct subType

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have around 35.500 documents in my database. **OfficeId** field, is in this format:

```json
  "OfficeId": {
    "$binary": {
      "base64": "bOKrjVPLTOCd5bYo6RYYOQ==",
      "subType": "03"
    }
  }
```

I think it was saved in the wrong format, because it appears that way:

```
OfficeId: BinData(3, 'bOKrjVPLTOCd5bYo6RYYOQ==')
```

Our pattern format of working wiht ids, is this:

```
_id: UUID('dd74f5e9-7928-412f-a482-e4b2fbfd437e')
```

If I change manualy the "subType" of the field to "04", it apears correctly:

```
OfficeId: UUID('6ce2ab8d-53cb-4ce0-9de5-b628e9161839')
```

In the near future, I will have to search that collection, using this field as UUID(Guid in C#).

In C# we Startup the applications calling this configuration:

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
```

That way, all the IDs are treated as Guid. So, I am afraid of the current format of that field, will produce us trouble, when it comes to search.

How would I update all the documents, just changing the 'subType" to "04"?
I tried it manualy and it worked. How can I do that to all documents?

**Ps1.: The field OfficeId is not the "_id" of the documents. It is a reference field.**

**Ps2.: Applying the *GuidRepresentation.Standard*, the new records are saved correctly.**